# Does React 18.2.0 support react-redux 7.2.4?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I am upgrading to react 18. Since adding children types is compulsory in react 18, so if I use react-redux 7.2.4 which does not seem to have explicit type declaration for children props, I get the error. However, if I use // @ts-ignore wherever I get the error, the error is resolved. However, I am not sure if react 18 is compatible with redux 7.2.4. Can anyone confirm whether It is fine to use the said version of react-redux or not?

Comment: You're probably better off bumping your react-redux to the next major version (v8) instead: it is recommended that v8 is used with React 18 https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v8.0.0. Using v7 with React 18 you're setting yourself up for issues further down the road.